# helm: how to mount configMap if not supported by values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am deploying authelia with their helm chart https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/truecharts/authelia.

I need to mount a ConfigMap to a specific file in the authelia container, however this is not available as a templated value in the `values.yaml`.

I'm struggling to understand what is the recommended way of doing something like this... this could generalise to "how can I customise an helm deployment beyond what is allowed through the `values.yaml`?"

I can only think of getting all the yaml from the chart, make the change I need and deploy like that... It can't be the best way of doing this

##### solution

###### users_database.yml

```yaml
###############################################################
#                         Users Database                      #
###############################################################

# This file can be used if you do not have an LDAP set up.

# List of users
users:
  admin:
    displayname: "admin"
    password: "redacted"
    email: admin@redacted
    groups:
      - admins
      - dev
```

###### patches/authelia_users_database.yaml

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: authelia
        volumeMounts:
        - name: authelia-users-database
          mountPath: /etc/config
      volumes:
      - name: authelia-users-database
        configMap:
          name: authelia-users-database
```

###### values.yaml

```yaml
authentication_backend:
  file:
    enabled: true
      path: /etc/config/users_database.yml
```

```
$ helm repo add authelia https://charts.authelia.com
$ helm repo update
$ helm upgrade --install authelia authelia/authelia --values values/authelia.yaml --version 0.8.34
$ kubectl create configmap authelia-users-database --from-file=users_database.yml --dry-run -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
$ kubectl patch daemonset authelia --patch-file patches/authelia_users_database.yaml
```

Comment: turns out, authelia official chart is actually https://charts.authelia.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you could try to use `kubectl patch` to mount the ConfigMap to the authelia container afterwards. [Look here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) for more information.

So create a `.yml` file with Deployment, Replicaset or Statefulset and add the ConfigMap configuration (just check which Kubernetes object suits best for you according to the Helm deployment). After deploying the application using the Helm chart; run the command `kubectl patch -f your-deployment-file.yml`.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be a straight forward, low maintenance, solution. I'll give this a try and report back

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I've updated my question with a step by step solution for authelia based on your answer

Answer (score 1):

Think of the helm package as it's a java package, you can't instantiate an object that has not been defined yet in that package and you are trying to do the same thing in helm.

If you are not familiar with **helm**, helm is a tool that helps you create abstraction on a specific k8s resources manifests and they are configured depending on you definition in `values.yaml`, each helm chart has its own deinition of templates, so If something you want to configure but isn't available yet in that chart you could either download the chart by running:

```bash
helm pull truecharts/authelia
# or 
helm fetch truecharts/authelia
```

extract the package then add your custom templates which as you said you are trying to refer to a configfile in your deployement so add a reference of that config in the **deployment.yaml** in the templates directory then if your definition and syntax are right you can add your specifications in the `values.yaml`.

Not sure how you want to bind your config but would that respong to your use case?

```yaml
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: {{ .Values.configmap }}
```

**values.yaml**

```yaml
...
configmap: myconfigmap
```

> make sure the configmap name specified exist so things work
>
> > make sure to read helm docs on how to [create your own templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/)

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a more comprehensive way of extending/altering charts. Given my current needs, I'll probably go with the simpler approach suggested by Lucas. However this appears to be the more "helm"y way of working. Would you recommend this approach instead of Lucas'? Should I end up making my own helm chart that has authelia's as a dependency?

Comment: Well depending on your use case I would say if you're not taking advantage of helm rolling back and revision control features, following Lucas's approach wouldn't be the right way since helm stores each revision as a configmap, if you manually patch some resources using kubectl then upgrading a revision, the day you want to roll back to that revision you manually patched, helm won't recognize what you havve patched since that action wouldn't be stored in the revision's configmap, and you might end up having some inconveniences.